# Set variable (reference) from dictionary to new value

Tags: swift, nsdictionary

How can i change the value of a variable that is referenced in a dictionary.

```
func setApiItem(name: String, setTo: String) {
    var refs = [
        "apiKey" : self.apiKey,
        "shipmentHost": self.shipmentHost,
        "shipmentPrinter": self.shipmentPrinter,
        "shipmentFormat": self.shipmentFormat,
        "orderHost": self.orderHost,
        "orderPrinter": self.orderPrinter,
        "orderFormat": self.orderFormat
    ]
    
    refs[name] = setTo // Don't work, won't change the variable value.
}
```

Im well aware **self.apiKey = setTo** would change the value, but how can i achieve this when the variable is stored in the dictionary?

Comment: So, if I'm understanding correctly, you want to modify a property of an object (like `self.apiKey`) by accessing it with a String? Is that what you're trying to accomplish by making the dictionary? Since Strings are value types in Swift, that won't work. You may find this thread useful: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/116041

Comment: Yes you understand me correctly @jnpdx, can you provide an answer as im new to swift?

Comment: What you are trying to do is not really conducive to the way Swift. Check out the link I sent you. I'd suggest, though, that it's likely that going this route may not be the best design decision (at least while using the Swift language). Is there a quick way to describe why you want to do this? Maybe someone can suggest a different solution.

Comment: it makes no sense: `refs[name]` is not a reference to apiKey, it just takes a value of apiKey. If you want to pass the name of the field as an argument and assign it to property of the class just do a switch: `switch name { case "apiKey": self.apiKey = setTo...` Or even better if you make an enum of the fields.